# Is EJB-2.0 transaction rollback undo/revert database changes?

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, ejb, rollback

Suppose I have written some transaction related code in my **ejb** bean method as follows:

```
UserTransaction utx = sessionContext.getUserTransaction();
try {
    int status = 0;
    utx.begin();
    status = 1;
    //SEGMENT- 1: UPDATE DATABASE

    //SEGMENT- 2: SOME OTHER CODE - which may throw Exception

    utx.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    utx.rollback();//SEGMENT- 3: My QUESTION at here, is it bollbak DATABASE changes also? 
                    // OR only rollback value of variable 'status' to '0'
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**1. BEGIN:** After starting my transaction `utx.begin();`

Changed java variable `status = 1;`

Changed database (**SEGMENT- 1**). e.g. some INSERT and UPDATE at DB

Then execute some other calculation (**SEGMENT- 2**)

 **2. COMMIT:** Now before commit `utx.commit()` 
Some Exception arise at (**SEGMENT- 2**)

 **3. ROLLBACK:** So catch block catches the Exception (**SEGMENT- 3**) and execute transaction rollback `utx.rollback()`.

**My QUESTION:**

Is `utx.rollback()` rollback 
All database changes and java variable changes?

**OR**
Only database changes

**OR** Only rollback java variable changes?

Comment: Memory isn't transactional, so variable value won't be changed. You need to do it manually in `catch` block.

Comment: @slwk - is **utx.rollback()** undo database changes made during transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All database changes made following the `utx.begin()` will be rolled back.

`utx.rollback()` has no effect on your java variables.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to extend **Steve C**'s answer

Another important point is, If we made any database level **COMMIT** then those changes never rollback by EJB `utx.rollback()`.

For example if we execute

```
stmt.executeUpdate("COMMIT");
```

Or execute `COMMIT` explicitly inside any package or stored procedure which is called
then database level commit occurs.